# Image blur detection with google vision ai

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision, vision

Is it possible to train a model that will detect cctv camera abnormally:

1. Camera blur (defocus)
2. Camera blocking (black image or blocked image)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A neural network model is too much for such tasks. Instead, you can try the following:

1. Process Gaussian noise to detect camera blur. You can start with reading papers such as [this](https://www.cv-foundation.org/openaccess/content_iccv_2015/papers/Chen_An_Efficient_Statistical_ICCV_2015_paper.pdf). Its code is available in [Github](https://github.com/zsyOAOA/noise_est_ICCV2015).
2. Have you read about color segmentation? If not, I recommend you this [presentation](https://web.stanford.edu/class/ee368/Project_03/Project/slides/ee368group05.ppt).

**The easier the better**. Try with naive approaches first, then you can escalate to more complex solutions.